# iOS 11/12 Autofill multiple textfields with contact data

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, autofill, ios12

I have an app that uses multiple text fields in which user provides their address and personal data (name, surname etc.).

I know that there is a property called `textContentType` on a `UITextField`. If I set it, the bar above the keyboard suggests the data correctly. But since the user has to go to the next text field manually, autofilling one field doesn't autofill all.

Is there a way to implement autofilling all fields the same way it's done on Safari, or in other places in the system, where user autofills only one field and then the form fills with selected contact data? Or would I have to use the `Contacts` framework to get the user's contact card?

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: I just used the `textContentType`, which fills the data correctly but fills only one textfield at a time.